# Avada resources still loading from localhost after database migration

Tags: theme-development, migration, virtual-hosts

I am using [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) to migrate WordPress website built with Avada from local to a VM.

I am doing a find and replace with 
Find: `//localhost/website` and Replace: `//10.60.8.118/website`

Find: `C:\xampp\htdocs\website` and Replace: `/var/www/html/website`

All the links are fine but fontawesome, icomoon and fonts which are being loaded from Avada are showing an error in console. I don't understand why still I have localhost URLs. (When I search for the term localhost in database I get no results)

**Access to Font at 'http://localhost/website/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0' from origin 'http://10.60.8.118' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://10.60.8.118' is therefore not allowed access.**

and so on. Also I get an error "URL can't be found" when I go to inner pages. (Note that I have reset my permalink and also checked .htaccess file which is default from WordPress)

May I know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue with your **file path** URL.
Still, Fontawesome trying to load fonts from "//localhost/website/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/fonts/"

Change all of your file path URL with your new site URL.

Comment: yes. That's what my question is. Why am I still getting localhost URLs if I have already replaced all the URLs.

Comment: the issue was: Avada was creating styles in the uploads folder with URLs having localhost.

Answer (score 3):

Avada > Theme Options > Advanced > Dynamic CSS & JS, and clear fusion cache.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: This was so promising.... Doesn't work in Avada / Fusion 5.8